# Cohomology rings of $S^3\times\mathbb{C} P^{\infty}$ and $S^1 \times \mathbb{C} P^{\infty}/(S^1 \times \{x_0\})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space

From Hatcher :

> Show that these two spaces have isomorphic cohomology rings

Elsewhere on this website I have seen someone claim that the latter space is a reduced suspension and hence have trivial cup product.
Whereas the first space has some ring coming from Kunneth formula which "doesn't seem" to have trivial multiplication, at least to me.

Can someone please elaborate.

Comment: The second space is not quite a reduced suspension.  $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ sits inside it as a retract, which should help you compute the structure of its cohomology ring.

Comment: The reduced suspension of $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ is the smash product $S^1\wedge \mathbb{C}P^\infty=(S^1\times\mathbb{C}P^\infty)/(S^1\times\ast\cup\ast\times\mathbb{C}P^\infty)$. The space you are asking about is $S^1_+\wedge\mathbb{C}P^\infty=(S^1\times\mathbb{C}P^\infty)/(S^1\times\ast)$, where $S^1_+=S^1\sqcup\{+\}$ is $S^1$ with a disjoint basepoint.

Comment: Okay makes sense.
For the product space Kunneth formula directly gives the ring.
What about the quotient space?

Comment: As @JHF points out, $A=\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ is a retract of $X=S^1\times\mathbb{C}P^\infty/S^1\times\ast$. The pair $(X,A)$ is good and $X/A\cong\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty$.